# What does Layer do in JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing

What does this property in the image do?

[image: Eclipse image]

Comment: Please read the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html

Comment: [`JInternalFrame#setLayer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#setLayer-int-). I'd also have a look at [`JDesktopPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) and [`JLayeredPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)